# Save web pages with rich content in local on Android

Tags: android, html, save

I need to save several web pages in html5 on android. Those pages could include content such as images, scripts for interactible application or video, and I am looking for ways to do that.
I've seen the saveWebArchive function of the webView. Is it able to save the html file, css, javascript and others images and sounds (I guess video is too much to ask for)?

If that does not work, any other workaround would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`saveWebArchive(path)` is from API-11. However, since API-19, `saveWebArchive(path)` will save in MHTML format (.mht files). It should save all the page's resources (HTML, CSS, Javascript etc):

> MHTML, short for MIME HTML, is a web page archive format used to combine in a single document the HTML code and its companion resources that are otherwise represented by external links (such as images, Flash animations, Java applets, and audio files). The content of an MHTML file is encoded as if it were an HTML e-mail message, using the MIME type multipart/related.

You can later on save this and reload it like so:

```
webView.loadUrl("file://" + path);
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, the minSdkVersion of the app is 14, and I have no say in this matter. Does that mean that saveWebArchive pre-19 cannot save all the ressources? And alternativly, where did you find these infos?

Comment: To ensure the functionality you want for API-8+, use this tiny library: https://github.com/gregko/WebArchiveReader

Comment: Did you test this solution to verify that it works?